# Erro em comunicação SOAP. Falta de caracter de encerramento de tag em XML

Tags: c#, delphi, web-service, soap, delphi-6

Precisei a algum tempo implementar comunicação com WebServices **SOAP** em aplicações legadas escritas em **Delphi 6**. Os WebServices que precisei realizar comunicação com esses sistemas **foram escritos em Delphi (versões mais novas com unicode) e C# (asax)**.

**Infelizmente não foi possível utilizar os componentes da paleta WebServices do Delphi 6, mas consegui copiar todas as unit's da paleta WebServices do Delphi 7** e adicionei nas aplicações em **Delphi 6**. Precisei realizar vários ajustes.

A comunicação tem funcionado bem. Ainda não foram detectados problemas com a comunicação dos sistemas com os WebServices disponibilizados em **C#**.

Um mesmo processo realizado em vários clientes funciona sem problemas, porém, esse mesmo processo, tem apresentado problemas em 2 ou três clientes. Essa comunição é com um WebService escrito com **Delphi (em versões mais novas)**.

O erro acredito ser específico. Em determinada requisição a seguinte excessão é lançada:

[image: Mensagem de erro]

Ela diz que não foi possível encontrar o caracter que encerra / determina o fechamento de uma tag.
A mensagem diz que o erro está na linha 2 da requisição.

Então, logo tratei de analisar o XML que está sendo gerado:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:NS1="urn:UntSecurityHeader" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
        <NS1:TSecurityHeader xsi:type="NS1:TSecurityHeader">
            <Identification xsi:type="xsd:string">2C0463C3BFC0DC44385BA3</Identification>
        </NS1:TSecurityHeader>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<NS2:Obter xmlns:NS2="urn:UntContracts-IContainerContract">
    <ContainerID xsi:type="xsd:int">0</ContainerID>
    <ContratoID xsi:type="xsd:int">0</ContratoID>
</NS2:Obter>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Esse XML, aberto pelo bloco de notas, copiado e colado aqui fica exatamente assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Header SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:NS1="urn:UntSecurityHeader"><NS1:TSecurityHeader xsi:type="NS1:TSecurityHeader"><Identification xsi:type="xsd:string">2C0463C3BFC0DC44385BA3</Identification></NS1:TSecurityHeader></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><NS2:Obter xmlns:NS2="urn:UntContracts-IContainerContract"><ContainerID xsi:type="xsd:int">0</ContainerID><ContratoID xsi:type="xsd:int">0</ContratoID></NS2:Obter></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Ou seja, tudo em apenas uma linha.
Aberto pelo IE, é apresentado assim:

[image: XML conforme apresentado no IE]

> Sei que a imagem ficou bem pequena, mas quis colocá-la aqui para aparecer exatamente como está no IE.
>
> **Efetuando um ZOOM no browser é possível ver com clareza o conteúdo.**

Decidi colocar essa imagem para demonstrar que é exatamente na segunda linha que o IE quebra o texto em duas linhas. Não sei se tem haver ou se a quebra é referênte apenas a formatação do browser para não ultrapassar o tamanho do documento.

Um outro detalhe que gostaria de adicionar é que, ao trabalhar com o WebService feito em Delphi geralmente tenho problemas com acentuação, enfim, caracteres especiais.
Já com os WebServices em C# isso não ocorre.

**Ambos os conjutos de WebService foram escritos e publicados por mim.**

**Tentei manipular o XML removendo caracteres de quebra de linha, efetuando replace do `#13#10`, pensando que poderia ser um problema de interpretação entre conjuntos de caracteres. Porém não resolveu também.**

Ressalto que em apenas poucos clientes, com sistemas Windows XP ao Seven, o problema ocorre.

Pode tratar-se de problemas de tipos de caracteres? O estranho é não ter tido esse tipo de problema com os WebServices escritos em C#.

Answer (score 1):

Posso estar enganado, mas algo me diz que o erro tem a ver com a forma de interpretar o XML pelo SOAP já que na maioria das máquinas ele funciona e somente algumas não. Experimente atualizar o protocolo nas maquinas onde não funciona. Creio que essa é a última versão : 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15697